# Display pdf in two columns on wide screen

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader, widescreen

Currently, I'm using a wide screen, and it does not feel good to view pdf files in one column on such a screen. So, I'm wondering whether it is possible to display the pdf files in two-columns. I'm using Adobe Reader DC now. But I'm willing to change to other software if it can achieve what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "two-columns", of course you could not see the same page divided in two columns.

But maybe you meant just to see two pages side-by-side. That could be easily achieved in Adobe Reader DC, by going to **View** in the menu bar, and clicking on **Page Display**, and therin clicking **Two Page View**.

Hope this answers your question.